# angularjs: How To concat object to string

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to concatinate object to string , below is my code.but its not working

```
var myobj = {
       name: 'test'
             }

   $operatorContainer.append($compile("<li><span ng-click=selectOperator(" + $operators[i].operator_name + ")><label for='checkbox1071' class='labeloperator'>" + $operators[i].operator_name + "</label><div class='custom-checkbox' style='height: 33px;'><input ng-checked='clickIt(op)' id='checkbox1071' ng-click='selectOperator()' name='tvoperator' type='radio'><label for='checkbox1071'></label></div></span></li>")(scope));
```

Comment: Maybe you want to use myobj.name for concatenation?

Comment: @MarcusBitzl- I tried it but still not working

Comment: In your example above, what exactly would you expect? How should the resulting HTML in your example look like?

Comment: You've changed your example so that `myobj` isn't used at all. So, again, what do you want to achieve and what result would you expect?

Answer (score 0):

you need to access the name attribute of the myobj

Comment: @Raju - I want to pass object not just a value.